# Issue with WSO2 ESB OutSequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am facing some issues with out-sequence in REST API. My use case is that I will receive json request, call a service, and if it is succcess then call second service. Right now I have skipped the check for first service response. I have a endpoint in the inSequence and another in outSequence. 
The issue is in the outSequence, it goes into infinite loop.

Please let me know what am I missing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context = "/content_filter" hostname = "localhost" name = "Content_Filter" port = "8282" xmlns = "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods = "POST" protocol = "http" uri-template = "/test/content_filter">
        <inSequence>
            <property action = "remove" description = "REST_URL_POSTFIX" name = "REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope = "axis2"/>
            <payloadFactory description = "payLoad-modifier" media-type = "json">
                <format>{"SvcValidateRq": {"UserAccountInfo": {"UserID": "$1", "Password": "$2"}}}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator = "json" expression = "$.UserAccountInfo.UserID"/>
                    <arg evaluator = "json" expression = "$.UserAccountInfo.Password"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <property description = "message_type" name = "messageType" scope = "default" type = "STRING" value = "application/json"/>
            <property description = "content_type" name = "ContentType" scope = "axis2" type = "STRING" value = "application/json"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address format = "rest" trace = "disable" uri = "http://10.202.17.86:8085/UserInfo/rest/v1/login"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <log description = "output_logger" level = "full"/>
            <property description = "output_content" name = "ContentType" scope = "axis2" type = "STRING" value = "application/json"/>
            <payloadFactory description = "payload" media-type = "json">
                <format>{"SvcValidateRq": {"UserAccountInfo": {"UserID": "f987d3b2-f5bf-4cc7-83e2-c08322dfaac0", "Password": "23776BD42FEB4F06812F30A01FC7F6FD"}}}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header description = "TimeStamp" name = "com.ugo.wallet.envelope.TimeStamp" scope = "transport" value = "7672387"/>
            <header description = "CorrelationID" name = "com.ugo.wallet.envelope.CorrelationID" scope = "transport" value = "9384982948"/>
            <header description = "TraceabilityID" name = "com.ugo.wallet.envelope.TraceabilityID" scope = "transport" value = "394892349"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address format = "rest" trace = "disable" uri = "http://10.202.17.86:8085/UserInfo/rest/v1/login"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <log description = "error_log" level = "full"/>
            <property description = "error_content" name = "ContentType" scope = "axis2" type = "STRING" value = "application/json"/>
            <send/>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Below is the output stack trace.

```
To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:77505542-4950-406c-95ff-b75541f03683, Direction: response, Payload: {"SvcValidateRs":{"Status":{"StatusCode":2,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Error","AdditionalStatus":[{"StatusCode":2036,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Invalid LoginID/Password","RefInfo":[{"KeyName":"FAILURE_INFO","KeyValue":["LoginID/Password is invalid."]},{"KeyName":"ORIGIN","KeyValue":["UserInfo.REST"]}]}]}}} {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:cdfc7f8b-0517-407f-a081-5196610853c0, Direction: response, Payload: {"SvcValidateRs":{"Status":{"StatusCode":2,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Error","AdditionalStatus":[{"StatusCode":2036,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Invalid LoginID/Password","RefInfo":[{"KeyName":"FAILURE_INFO","KeyValue":["LoginID/Password is invalid."]},{"KeyName":"ORIGIN","KeyValue":["UserInfo.REST"]}]}]}}} {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:049dd134-b29d-4abe-9653-0f3501a76e0a, Direction: response, Payload: {"SvcValidateRs":{"Status":{"StatusCode":2,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Error","AdditionalStatus":[{"StatusCode":2036,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Invalid LoginID/Password","RefInfo":[{"KeyName":"FAILURE_INFO","KeyValue":["LoginID/Password is invalid."]},{"KeyName":"ORIGIN","KeyValue":["UserInfo.REST"]}]}]}}} {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:5156f9e8-5d6b-432b-b016-59175583b663, Direction: response, Payload: {"SvcValidateRs":{"Status":{"StatusCode":2,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Error","AdditionalStatus":[{"StatusCode":2036,"Severity":"Error","StatusDesc":"Invalid LoginID/Password","RefInfo":[{"KeyName":"FAILURE_INFO","KeyValue":["LoginID/Password is invalid."]},{"KeyName":"ORIGIN","KeyValue":["UserInfo.REST"]}]}]}}} {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove following from the out sequence. In the ESB when a response is recieved it will be triggering the outsequence hence you are seeing the Infinite loop. You can use call mediators instead of Send mediators within the in sequence to avoid this.

```
<send>
<endpoint>
<address format = "rest" trace = "disable" uri = http://10.202.17.86:8085/UserInfo/rest/v1/login"/>
</endpoint>
</send>
```

Following is a good artical to cover your use case.

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/02/service-orchestration-with-wso2-esb/

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. 
I am not sure, but when I use Call mediator, the service call do not happen. But things work with Send mediator. 
I am able to solve the issue, both the URLs in inSequence and outSequence where same. I changed the URL of outSequence and it is working fine now.